# Opening spreadsheet in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, automation

I'm trying to automate the creation of a spreadsheet in Google. I'm able to create and edit the spreadsheet just fine. The problem I'm having is opening.

```
function CoS(){
  var Sheet = SSheet.getActiveSheet();
  var bill = Sheet.getActiveCell().getValues();
  var nSheet = NewCoS(bill);
  var file = DocsList.getFileById(nSheet.getId());

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(file); //Doesn't work the way I need it to
  Browser.msgBox(ss.getName());
}
```

I've tryed `.openByUrl` and `.openById`. In the documentation I read that these are for opening in the background but `.open` seems to do the same thing. However the documentation doesn't state explicitly that that is what it's meant for. `Browser.msgbox()` works so it seems logical that the file is getting opened in the background. I also can't find anything like `Spreadsheet.visiblity()` or `Spreadsheet.show()` as I would expect in excel.

I've even looked in other libraries like Drive and DocsList.

Is there a way to open my spreadsheet through script so that the user can see it?

Answer (score 0):

Opening a spreadsheet means "*get read and write access to that sheet*", it does not mean "*show this spreadsheet in my browser*".

If you need to get such a  functionality then use a href link (in HTMLService) or an anchor widget (in UiApp) that will redirect you to another browser tab/window with that spreadsheet.

Note also that there is no SpreadsheetApp.open method, use the autocompletion in the script editor to be sure about available methods in Google Apps Script.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the HTMLservice approach. There is an open() method. I did use auto complete and referenced the documentation.